# How do I solve closed loop integrals around 2 dimensional curves?

Tags: integration

I'll make my question more clear with this example:

$\oint (x^2y \ dx \ +3y\ dy\ +z^2y\ dz) \quad$ around $\ x^2+y^2=1 \quad [1]$

I was given the following solution:

$ x^2+y^2=1 \ \rightarrow \ z=0 \ \rightarrow dz=0$

let $x=\cos t \quad and \quad y=\sin t  \rightarrow \oint (x^2y \ dx \ +3y \ dy)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\cos^2t\sin^2t \ dt \ +3 \sin t \cos t \ dt) $

and the rest were simple calculations.

My only problem with this solution is that, why does z have to equal $0$, or as a matter of fact, any constant? Don't the points satisfying  [1] form a cylinder along the z direction? If they do, why are we saying $z=0$, we technically don't have a curve to evaluate our integral along, we have a surface. Am I right in saying any of this? If so, what is the correct solution or interpretation of this solution?

Comment: Is the one-form closed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a line integral, thus it cannot be a surface integral. I think you have a point saying that you should not take $z=0$ arbitrarily. To be more precise, the exercise should mention what $z$ you should consider. Note, however, that this wouldn't change anything in practice. This is because, for any (constant) $z$ (or height of the cylinder, as you mentioned), you should have $dz = 0$, so the your final integral would be the same, whatever the choice of $z$ is. Thus, it seems easier to take $z=0$.

Comment: Is there a reason why we should take a constant value of z and evaluate the line integral at that value? Sorry if I wasn't very clear with my question, but I'm mainly struggling to understand why we're only taking curves with a constant z from the whole surface of points (the cylinder) that satisfy the equation of our "curve".

Comment: The question is that you have to evaluate your line integral over a certain domain. So, the domain in chosen to be a circle. The only possibility is to fix some z, because otherwise you would be a hole cylinder as domain, which males no sense as a domain for a linearidade integral.